# How can I run a function at specific time & date (React)?

Tags: reactjs

I need to remove React elements (a button) and change text at a certain time and day and I was wondering if there is a way to do it dynamically so that way i don't have to set an alarm and change it manually.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple ways to do this but i would do this:

1. Check current time in `componentDidMount`
2. Set component hidden or visible by using `this.setState`
3. Use `setTimeout` to setup a function to change visibility of the button when needed again.

Comment: Hey Lalli, thanks for your help! i'm new to React, are you able to give a concrete example so I could wrap my head around of how to make this work?